# Margins only between floated divs

Tags: css

Is it possible to create margin only between floated divs **without margins on the sides of parent**.

So basically:

```
no margin <div> |margin| <div> |margin| <div> |margin| <div> no margin
no margin <div> |margin| <div> |margin| <div> |margin| <div> no margin
no margin <div> |margin| <div> |margin| <div> |margin| <div> no margin
no margin <div> |margin| <div> |margin| <div> |margin| <div> no margin
no margin <div> |margin| <div> |margin| <div> |margin| <div> no margin
```

like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `first-child` and `last-child` selectors to specify no left/right margin, respectively:

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/bzSgp/1

In case you have other elements between the first/last divs, you can use `first-of-type`/`last-of-type` instead.

Comment: Your example only working if there is one row of floated divs, here is upgraded example http://jsfiddle.net/bzSgp/3/

Comment: Nope random photos, random sizes.

Comment: @Somebody in that case what you're asking is not possible with CSS alone without a mass of media queries and `nth-child` rules because there is no semantic way of knowing where one of the divs will "sit."  If JavaScript is an option (especially jQuery) it would be very simple, though.

Comment: Yea i guess js is the only option here, ok topic closed. )

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, to dig that one up, but it just showed up after a google search on that topic:

That's why I'd like to point out that there *is* a CSS-only solution using **negative margins** on a wrapping DIV when the widths of containing elements are known (i mostly use percentages here)

```
.wrapper { 
    margin: -1em;
    overflow:hidden; /* or other clearfix if you need overflow */
}
.item {
    margin: 1em;
    float:left;
    /* ... */
}
```

I have also put together a quick [demo pen](http://codepen.io/Grilly86/pen/MYQLKq).

For example, [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)'s grid system works in a similar way!

--

A big advantage of this approach is, you don't have to know exactly how many items will fit in a row (as you would have to know for the :nth-child() approach). So it's much easier to handle for different screen sizes.